# Using the Stylish chrome extension to override this font

Tags: css, google-chrome-extension, stylish

I would like to override the font of [web.ebuddy.com](http://web.ebuddy.com/?startsession=1#) to Helvetica (the font of my messages).

I have tried doing

```
#bodyContent {
    font-family: Helvetica;
}
```

and it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

When using Stylish, one often has to employ the `!important` flag.  Also, provide a fallback font in case Helvetica is not installed (it wasn't on some of my windows machines).

So this should work:

```
#bodyContent {
    font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif !important;
}
```

**unless** the content in question is in an iframe.  Iframes in Google Chrome are sometimes impossible for Stylish to reach.

Comment: This didn't work. What can I do if it's in an iframe?

Comment: If the iframe has a `src` attribute, set your Stylish script to run on that page or domain.

Comment: src=""   Any other suggestions?

Comment: That's the case where we are most screwed in Chrome.  You'll have to write a complicated userscript, or just switch to Firefox.  There's a bug/feature request for Chrome to fix this issue.  Look it up and add your support to it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the all selector?

Like this:

```
* { font-family: Helvetica; }
```

Comment: I just tried it. It still doesn't look like Helvetica. It seems to insist on using the few fonts in the options.